# Porque está dando erro castException?

Tags: java

O código abaixo resulta no erro **CastException**. Como posso solucionar isto?

```
private void popularTabela(){
    ClienteDAO clidao = new ClienteDAO();

    Cliente clienteFiltro = new Cliente();
    Integer codigoPesq = null;
    Cidade cidadeFiltro = ((Cidade) cmbCidPesq.getSelectedItem());
    if (!txtCodigoPesq.getText().equals("")){
        codigoPesq = Integer.parseInt(txtCodigoPesq.getText());
    }
    clienteFiltro.setCodigo(codigoPesq);
    clienteFiltro.setNome(txtNomePesq.getText());
    clienteFiltro.setCidade(cidadeFiltro);

    //clienteFiltro.setCidade((Cidade) cmbCidPesq.getSelectedItem());

    List<Cliente> clientes = clidao.pesquisar(clienteFiltro);
    DefaultTableModel modeloTable = (DefaultTableModel) jTable1.getModel();
    while (modeloTable.getRowCount() > 0){
        modeloTable.removeRow(0);
    }
    for (Cliente c : clientes){
        modeloTable.addRow(new Object[]{c.getCodigo(),c.getNome(),c.getCidade(),c.getVeiculo()});
    }
}
```

Comment: Qual a linha que dá essa exceção?

Comment: Meu palpite: Se o erro for nessa linha: Cidade cidadeFiltro = ((Cidade) cmbCidPesq.getSelectedItem()); Então é pq o método está retornando um valor ou objeto que não pode ser diretamente convertido para Cidade por não ser uma subclasse de Cidade. Nesse caso você precisa pegar esse valor e instanciar uma nova Cidade.

Comment: Poste o código onde popula o combo

Comment: Poste seu combomodel. Se não tiver um, ai está o problema do cast.

Comment: É bom incluir o stack trace nesses casos

Comment: Valeu galera, descobri que meu método popular tabela estava antes do popular cidade por isso estava dando o erro. Consegui ajustar mas valeu pelas resposta ai.